# Firebase Signout Triggers Before Other Firebase Actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there any reason why I'm being signed out before my firebase actions are done finishing?

**What Should Happen:**

I first make a post request to my server to update values in my db.
Then I update the users firebase email if its changed.
Then I update the email if its changed as well.
Then finally I want to sign the user out.

**What Happens:**

I instantly gets signed out and then get errors in my console because the other actions couldn't be completed.

I have tried to trail the .then() after my axios post as well but I still had the same issue of being instantly signed out.

```
export const updateUserData = (userData) => {
    return (dispatch, getState, {getFirebase}) => {
        const state = getState();
        const firebase = getFirebase()

        let user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
        let cred = firebase.auth.EmailAuthProvider.credential(user.email, userData.oldPassword);

        user.reauthenticateWithCredential(cred).then(() => {
            axios.post('/updateUserData', {
                uid: state.firebase.auth.uid,
                email: userData.email,
                firstName: userData.firstName,
                lastName: userData.lastName,
                devices: userData.devices,
            }, {
                headers: {
                    "Authorization": `${state.firebase.auth.stsTokenManager.accessToken}`,
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                withCredentials: true
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log("Failed Email Change: " + err)
            });
        }).then(() => {
            if (state.firebase.auth.email !== userData.email) {
                firebase.auth().currentUser.updateEmail(userData.email).then(() => {
                    console.log("Email Changed")
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Failed Email Change: " + err)
                });
            }
        }).then(() => {
            if (userData.newPassword.length !== 0) {
                firebase.auth().currentUser.updatePassword(userData.newPassword).then(() => {
                    console.log("Successful Password Change")
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log("Failed Password Change: " + err)
                });
            }
        }).then(() => {
            firebase.auth().signOut().then(null)
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: If you were to remove the firebase logout, would all the other firebase actions complete successfully?

Comment: Yes, they would all complete successfully

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't returning values from your promise chains. If you want an async action to take place after another one when using Promises, you need to return them:

```
// don't do this
doThing().then(() => {
  doSomethingElse().then(() => { /* ... */ });
}).then(() => {
  // this will happen before doSomethingElse is finished
  finallyDoThing();
});

// instead do this
doThing().then(() => {
  return doSomethingElse();
}).then(() => {
  return finallyDoThing();
});
```

Comment: Ouu, adding return statements to the post request and the other firebase actions fixed it. Thank  you